# Изображения в БД Android

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite, изображения

Объясните, как хранить много изображений в локальной базе данных в Android приложении и затем их выводить в `ImageView`. С `ImageView` знаю как работать, но вот с БД проблемы. Помогите пожалуйста.
Можете скинуть код и объяснить?

Comment: Вы бы указали более подробную информацию, а то не понятно у вас предзаданный набор изображений или подгружаются из интернета, и могут варироваться. Просто при разных раскладах, можно предложить разные варианты.)

Answer (score 4):

Изображения надо хранить в виде строк-путей к файлам. Сами изображения хранить в БД не нужно.
Поместите ваши изображения в проект в папку  assets и запишите в БД путь к ним/их имена. После получайте их по этим адресам.

Comment: вот так точно не надо делать :)

Comment: @andreich, вы не могли бы подробнее рассказать что именно и почему не надо делать? =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Если использовать цифровые ID из R файла, то при добавлении какого-то ресурса файлик перегенерится, а значения в базе останутся такими же.))

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко, ой, да, точно) Убрал это)

Answer (score 4):

Хранить изображения в БД можно, НО будет серьезная проблема с производительностью, которой можно избежать при работе с файлами.

Чтобы достать изображение из базы нужно прочитать байтовый массив из blob'а в память, притом сразу целиком, который далее будет собран сборщиком мусора и тормознет приложение. Если таких загрузок будет несколько, приложение будет заметно заикаться, особенно если в этот момент будут какие-то анимации. Непосредственно скорость обработки изображений из файла и из базы отличается в полтора-два раза не в пользу базы (тестил на Genymotion).

Поэтому хранить картинки нужно в файлах, пути к картинкам - в базе. 
Еще лучше, сохранять картинки на диск под генерящимися именами. 
И совсем правильно использовать Picasso или UIL для загрузки, хранения, отображения картинок.